# Add specific criterias to an existing macro

Tags: vba

I have tried searching on this site but I don't really know what I'm looking for.  I have the below macro which works well(taken from this site), but I want to add more values for it to check and delete. Where "AGGF" is what it looks for and removes, I have several other words that I would like it to search for and remove. Can I somehow use 'OR' after AGGF so that I can do this?

```
Sub AUMReport()
'
' AUMReport Macro
'   Dim lRow As Long
    Dim iCntr As Long
    lRow = 390
    For iCntr = lRow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(iCntr, 1).Value = "AGGF" Then
            Rows(iCntr).Delete
                    End If
        Next

'
End Sub
```

Comment: Please format your code as code and state what programming language you are using in the tags. I've done it for you, this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `Select Case` instead of `If Then`:

```
Sub AUMReport()
'
' AUMReport Macro
Dim lRow As Long
Dim iCntr As Long
lRow = 390
For iCntr = lRow To 1 Step -1
    Select Case Cells(iCntr, 1).Value
        Case "my-first-value", "my-second-value", "my-third-value", "my-etc"
        Rows(iCntr).Delete
    End Select
Next

'
End Sub
```